# How to implement Trumbowyg in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trumbowyg

I want to know how properly implement this gem:
[Trumbowyg_rails](https://github.com/TikiTDO/trumbowyg_rails)

I add all required files.
(//= require trumbowyg/trumbowyg,

//= require trumbowyg/langs/pl

*= require trumbowyg/trumbowyg)

Part of view form.html.haml

```
  .form-group
    = f.text_area :meaning, class: 'form-control', id: 'trumbowyg', rows: 10, placeholder: "Wpisz treść..."
  .form-group.text-right
    = link_to :back, class: "btn btn-primary" do
      %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left

    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success"

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#trumbowyg').trumbowyg({
          lang: 'pl'
      });

  });
```

Unfortunately above code displays plain textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forget the icons,
try to put the file `icons.svg` under assets/images/`, then

```
 $('#trumbowyg').trumbowyg({
     svgPath: '<%= image_path("icons.svg")%>'
 });
```

Hope can help you

Comment: Yes, I had to copy the icons from the gem to my vendor/assets/images folder and tell it the path as you described before the plugin would load. Your solution was helpful, thanks!